# My Putty session hangs out after sometime

Tags: windows-7, putty

Everything was ok few days ago but every now and then i see that my putty sesison is hanging out in between after any random interval of time.

Sometime remians ok even after 5 hours and sometimes hangs after 2 mins while i am working.

How can i find out whats the problem

Comment: is the session to a machine on the local network or to a machine over the internet?

Comment: Its on the remote server with ssh and password less login with keys

Comment: @Mirage, Is the session through LAN or WLAN?

Comment: @Mirage, probable answer can be found here: [Putty Session freezes](https://superuser.com/questions/145035/putty-freezes-at-random-when-logging-into-a-remote-machine-in-another-continent)
It also happens when a machine is accessed through WLAN, and there are weak Wi-Fi signal and less timeout for the particlar putty session.